# Подсветка областей карты Yandex

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте. Интересует каким образом происходит подсветка областей карты при наведении на определенную зону (вот пример http://e-dostavka.by/#/dzone/). Нужная карта у меня уже есть и на ней отмечены все области, осталось лишь сделать подсветку нужной области при наведении на определенный текст.

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавляем полигоны областей на карту и запоминаем их соответствие `id` "определенного текста" (или просто порядкового номера);
2. Прослушиваем события `mouseenter` и `mouseleave` у "определенного текста";
3. При получении события меняем параметры отображения (цвет рамки, заливка, прозрачность...) соответствующего полигона.

Comment: Вот первый пункт можно более подробно?
Вот что мне возвращает api
http://jsfiddle.net/DoBrbI/c69hbrp4/

Comment: @neek Это он на какой запрос возвращает? Добавьте в вопрос кусок кода, который у вас уже есть

Comment: @tutankhamon Спасибо за помощь, уже все сделал. Я просто полученную ссылку в конструкторе вставил в строку браузера и получил массив данных. Там и получил всю нужную информацию.